# ASP.net Multiple variables and queries into querystring

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2015

I am using Visual Studio 2015 and Entity Framework 6.  I need to pass multiple variables that are query strings to another page.

Also:
Status is a dropdownlist (ddlStatus)
Name is a dropdownlist (ddlFlowers)
vase is a radiobuttonlist (rbList)

This is what i have:

```
protected void btnEditOrder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LinkButton lnk = sender as LinkButton;
            string orderID = lnk.CommandArgument;
        string name = lnk.CommandArgument;
        string delivery = lnk.CommandArgument;
        string status = lnk.CommandArgument;
        string message = lnk.CommandArgument;
        string vase = lnk.CommandArgument;
        string cost = lnk.CommandArgument;



        Response.Redirect("EditOrder.aspx?orderID=" + orderID);}
```

I've tried it a few different ways, but it isn't working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding them in this manner to the URL?

```
Response.Redirect("EditOrder.aspx?orderID=" + orderID + "&name=" + name + "&delivery=" + delivery);
```

EDIT: Also, for the commandArgument, you should be able to pass multiple parameters like so:

```
CommandArgument='<%# Eval("OrderMessage") + ";" + Eval("OrderCost") %>'
```

Comment: I hope this could be of help. Please accept this answer, if this resolved the issues for you.

Comment: im getting a compilation error putting in the multiple commandarguments

Comment: oops, nevermind its back.   Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0123: No overload for 'btnEditOrder_Click' matches delegate 'EventHandler'